# Is it possible to directly interface a MEMS ADMP541 microphone over I2S with any Microcontroller?

Tags: communication, microphone, controller, mems, i2s

I have bought a MEMS ADMP541 Evalution kit to record voice samples with arduino controller

MEMS microphone will produce digital o/p , I2S communication protocal

My question is should I directly connect the MEMS microphone to arduino mega/ any controller ?

Or do I need to use any interfacing circuite b/w mic and controller

Comment: What do the data sheets say?

Comment: If your Arduino has I2S I fail to see a problem.

Comment: MEMS microphone data sheet   http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/obsolete-data-sheets/ADMP521.pdf     MY APPLICATION IS To RECORD THE VOICE SAMPLES with 22K sampling rate , SO i can use only 1 microphone , which channel is good for recording voice samples Left or Right ?   , the data sheet says we can interphase the one microphone with codec ic  but after that i dont have any idea how to impliment in both s/w n h/w with MSP430 controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most microcontrollers have an SPI port, but not that many have an I2S. An SPI port could be used to communicate with an I2S microphone, with a few caveats, mainly the SPI bus usually works with 8 bits bytes and the I2S with 16 bits words, and the I2S requires a Lef-Right clock signalling to indicate when the data is coming from the left or right in an stereo microphone. If you are using audio in mono, and your microcontroller allows to change from 8 bits to 16 bits registers (some of them do), you can use it. See [Interfacing an I2S Device to an MSP430 Device](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa449a/slaa449a.pdf)

Comment: well that was a great ping for me , my application is to record the voice samples with 22K sampling rate using external button interrputs, I have choosen to go with MSP430

Comment: i would like to purchase the ADMP441 MEMS microphone it has I2S Digital o/p   https://www.tindie.com/products/Fyberlabs/mems-microphone-flex-module/    DO i interphease this I2S mic with MSP432 using SPI protocall

Answer (score 1):

I find this MEMS microphone : [ADMP504](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/obsolete-data-sheets/ADMP504.pdf)
As you can see this microphone has a analog output so you need to connect it to a dedicated codec microphone input [ADAU1761](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADAU1761.pdf). The codec is connected to a controller via I2C. If your microphone has an integrated codec than you can connect it directly to the arduino without a problem.

Comment: If you are using an analog microphone, you don't even need a codec IC, it is enough with a simple opamp connected directly to the ADC of the microcontroller. Sparkfun has a breakout board with that same microphone and the opamp circuit, ready to connect.

Comment: Ha yes, that i have done earlier using MAX9814 AGC microphone amplifier board connect through a analog port of arduino mega , this is for making a concept is ready , but now i have to do with a low power n good perfomance based controller and that to the h/w should be as small as possible

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one library for the Arduino Due to communicate with I2S audio devices.

[Arduino Playground (list of libraries.)](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/LibraryList)

[Arduino Due I2S github.](https://github.com/delsauce/ArduinoDueHiFi)

Comment: thank you , how would i interphase the ADMP541 mic to arduino controller